# recursion isn't working 2nd time. - python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, recursion, multiple-return-values

```
def twothousand(amt):
    n=500
    div1=amt//n
    mod1=amt%n
    return (mod1,n,div1)


def fivehundred(amt):
    n=200
    div1=amt//n
    mod1=amt%n
    return (mod1,n,div1)


def calculate(amt):
    if amt <10:
        print("hi")

    elif amt>=200 and amt<500:
        mod1,n,div1=fivehundred(amt)
        return (mod1,n,div1)

        #the above return statement isn't returning anything. 
        #That is, now the program doesn't go to the main function 2nd time.

    elif amt>=500 and amt<2000:
        mod1,n,div1=twothousand(amt)
        return (mod1,n,div1)


def main1():
    amt=int(input("Enter the amount: "))
    mod1,n,div1=calculate(amt)
    print (mod1,n,div1)
    #The above print function executes only once.
    if mod1!=0:
        amt=mod1
        calculate(amt)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main1()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter the amount: 1700
200 500 3
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
Enter the amount: 1700
200 500 3
0 200 1
```

I'm unable to execute return statement after calculate() function call happens 2nd time, as written in comments.
I'm not getting the second output. New to python, kindly help.

sorry for not updating the logic earlier . 
The logic is:

When user asks for an amount of 1700, he can only be given that amount using 500 and 200 currency. So, the 1st output is - 200 500 3 ; that is, 3 number of 500 currency.. and remaining is 200. 
I want to call the function calculate till the value mod1 == 0.

Comment: why shud it print 0 200 1 ? there is no logic written in any of the functions that it shud run recursively?

Comment: for the 2nd time, it needs to go to fivehundred() function, comeback to the elif loop inside calculate function and return the value. 
It is doing everything, but the last step isn't happening. That's it's not returning any value to the main.

Comment: Your code will break when the value is greater than 10 and less than 200 as their is no "IF" block

Comment: There are precisely 0 recursive calls being made in your code. Recursion is defined as when a function calls itself. Not when you repeatedly call a function. What are you *trying* to do? Do you want to keep calling `calculate` until `mod1 == 0`?

Comment: yes! i want to keep calling calculate until mod1==0. 
sorry for not updating the logic earlier .


The logic is: 
When user asks for an amount of 1700, he can only be given that amount using 500 and 200 currency. So, the 1st output is - 200 500 3 ; that is, 3 number of 500 currency.. and remaining is 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main() function should look like this:

```
def main1():
    amt=int(input("Enter the amount: "))
    mod1,n,div1=calculate(amt)
    print (mod1,n,div1)
    #The above print function executes only once.
    if mod1!=0:
        amt=mod1
        mod1,n,div1 = calculate(amt)
        print (mod1,n,div1)
```

Comment: still getting the same result. 

logic is : - 
When user asks for an amount of 1700, he can only be given that amount using 500 and 200 currency. So, the 1st output is - 200 500 3 ; that is, 3 number of 500 currency.. and remaining is 200 .

Comment: It is coming same just like your expected output...edited the answer...please check now!!

Comment: Thank you. Got it! Earlier, i added the code in "if" of calculate function. sorry about that.

Comment: I did. But, it says, votes cast by less that 15 rep points are recorded but doesn't change publicly displayed post score. lol This is my 1st time on stackoverflow. I've clicked the accept though. thanks.